# ScrollTo jQuery code that can be re-used

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I'm trying to make a simple menu, every li tag, when clicked uses scrollTop to navigate.

```
<div class="menu" id="menu1">
   <ul>
    <li class="button1">Section1</li>
    <li class="button2">Section2</li>
    <li class="button3">Section3</li>
    <li class="button4">Section4</li>
    <li class="button5">Section5</li>
   </ul>
</div>

$(".button1").click(function() {

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.section1').offset().top-55
    });
});
```

The thing is I have several parts which need to use the same logic but applied to different sections, so mainly I don't want to write an individual code for each one, rather a code which applied to each menu can solve this for me. I know it's a lot to ask, but I am rather new at this.

Answer (score 0):

Use a common `class` on each of your `<li>` elements. I see you have classes now, however they are unique, these should probably be ID's. A common class they could share for example is `menuButton`, then your function could be:

```
$(".menuButton").click(function() {
    //var elementID = this.id <--Optional variable containing the clicked element ID

    //Sample logic
    //if (elementID == "button1") { animate this way } )
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.section1').offset().top-55
    });
});
```

Modified HTML:

```
<div class="menu" id="menu1">
    <ul>
        <li id="button1" class="menuButton">Section1</li>
        <li id="button2" class="menuButton">Section2</li>
        <li id="button3" class="menuButton">Section3</li>
        <li id="button4" class="menuButton">Section4</li>
        <li id="button5" class="menuButton">Section5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, the thing is that I would still need to make unique id's for every menu. That's exactly the problem. I have many menus in one section, so for menu1 it's fine, but for menu2, I would have to use button1_2, and add another line of code for each button.

Comment: I have serious issues reading. I get what you are saying with the commented lines. I am going to try them and see if it works. thanks!

Comment: This helped me organize a bit, but it still needs some work which I haven't been able to solve. The thing is this works fine for one section and one menu. But I have many sections which have many menus on the same page, each hidden and unhidden when prompted.